# tcsh: print all arguments, ignore first, and match with grep

Tags: regex, grep, tcsh

I am pretty new to tcsh. I found out how to print out all the arguments onto separate lines with

```
#! /bin/tcsh
foreach i ($*)
   echo $i
end
```

Great! Now, I want to **not print out the first element** and use ***grep*** to test whether the first argument matches any of the patterns in the other arguments.

The idea is that if someone types **./prog bread '^b' 'x'**
it should output

```
^b : b
x : no match
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

# Store first element in variable
set first="$1"

# `shift` removes the first (from the left) element from $*
shift

# Now iterate trough the remaining args
foreach i ($*)
    # Grep for $i in $first and send results to /dev/null
    echo "$first" | grep "$i" >& /dev/null

    # Check the return value of the last command
    if ( $? == 0 ) then
        echo "$i : matched"
    else
        echo "$i : no match"
    endif
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that hits most of the right points, except it only matches if it is the same exact string. Like, ./prog cat cat gives a match for cat but ./prog cat c or ./prog cat ^c does not return a match when it should. Is that because of the if ( $? == 0) line?

Comment: Also, that point aside, it is a very well commented and organized answer.

Comment: do you want to search for argument two in argument one? (will be back ~hour..)

Comment: This is using the first argument as the pattern to match against all other arguments. That's inverted from the request. Replace the `grep` line with `echo "$first" | grep -q "$i"` to get what you want I think.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, and for argument 3 in one etc. I apologize for my mistake.